# Save Image File Containing Slash - cPanel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using a PHP Thumb Creating script that save file with the file name that I manually input or My blog Post's name..

But when I Save a Image file name or Post name Containing Slash, Example: `php/html/css tricks logo.jpg`, it's not saving and showing error.

I checked my File Manager, That image is saving with file name: `phphtmlcss tricks logo.jpg` and I want to vew this image in my like this:  `src="name.domain/php/html/css tricks logo.jpg"`

Is there any `.htaccess` function to solve this?

Note that, in my cPanel I can't not able to save a file that containing slash in name and I also can't use `urlencode()` for some reasons.

Comment: Its a very basic thing , you should learn that a file name cannot have forward slash /  its against the file system rules. There is nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Slashes in most operating systems have special meaning. They are used after folder names, to separate folders and files (e.g. `folder1/folder2/file.txt`). In file names you need to either remove them or replace them with another character. The `-` character is a good one.